# How to create installer package with custom artstyle?

Tags: publishing, installer

When you publish a finished game you might consider making, for example, a Windows installer package.

I have found quite a few applications that can do that. But I couldn't find any that support changing the appearance of an installation process.

Many games support that, so I have been wondering where could I find an application like this? I doubt that every game studio creates its own one.

Preferably the one that supports Unity files.

EDIT:
Examples

[image: Install wizard]

[image: Install wizard AOE]

Comment: What do you mean by "changing the appearance"? Lots of common installers support custom images in its installation steps. Or do you mean a completely different UI? Can you post an example of what you're going for?

Comment: Have you checked out NSIS [http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page]

Comment: @congusbongus I have edited the question. Completely different.

Comment: @GeorgeHanna Thank you, I must have missed that it can be used to change the graphics. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JffX4s2DUW8